# Как сделать чтобы цветные блоки начинались справа налево?

Tags: css

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

На картинке показан блок воронки продаж. Никак не могу понять как сделать чтобы цветные полоски начинались справа налево, а не как щас. Помогите.

```
.conv-status-block {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 42%; 
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.conv-status {
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    font: 24px/24px "Ubuntu Condensed", Arial, "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.conv-status-1 { background-color: #FFD700; }
.conv-status-2 { background-color: #FF7F50; }
.conv-status-3 { background-color: #FA8072; }
.conv-status-4 { background-color: #90EE90; }
.conv-status-5 { background-color: #ccc; }
.conv-status sup {
    font: 14px/14px "Ubuntu Condensed", Arial, "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;
}

.conv-title-block {
    float: right;
    width:45%;
}
.conv-title {
    text-align:left;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    font: 20px/10px "Ubuntu Condensed", Arial, "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.conv-title:before {
    margin-top: 22px;
    content: " ";
    height:1px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.conv-status-1 { float: right; background-color: #FFD700; }`
и т.д включая 5тую

Comment: хах! Сижу ржу над собой! Спасибо!

Comment: Если вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его как принятый.

Comment: Можно упростить до одной строчки:  `[class^="conv-status-"] { float: right; }`